# How to draw a linear gradient around a circle on android device

Tags: java, android

I cannot figure out how to implement LinearGradient so that I can draw a fill with a gradient like so [image]

around a circle as a fill like so: [image]

Maybe I am going about it in the wrong way??

```
canvas.drawArc(rectF, startPosInDegrees, angle, false, foregroundPaint);
```

I was trying to implement a LinearGradient as "foregroundPaint" and draw a new new LinearGradient around the circle.

How can I achieve the result depicted above??

I based the above on the code found here:

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3186

I just added the following, which is completely foo-bar:

```
  public void setLinearGradientPaintWithAngle(Paint paint, float left, float top,
                                   float right, float bottom, int[] colors2) {

    double angle = 90;
    double angleInRadians = Math.toRadians(angle);
    double length = 100; //Don't know what this is yet.
    double rightWithAngle = Math.cos(angleInRadians) * right;
    double bottomWithAngle = Math.sin(angleInRadians) * bottom;

    LinearGradient linearGradient = new LinearGradient(left, top, (float) rightWithAngle, (float) bottomWithAngle, colors2, null, TileMode.CLAMP);

    paint.setShader(linearGradient);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using RadialGradient? It would be more appropriate for a circle.

Comment: Could that work here?  I need to fill the circle progressively clockwise. Like a progress bar.

Comment: Could you paste the code you have now?

Comment: Not much to it. Every time an event occurs I (try to) draw the lineargradient and then increase the arc that holds the fill. This code is base up the example found here: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3186

Comment: Ok. I figured out how to use a radialGradient (sort of):  RadialGradient rg = new RadialGradient(rectF.centerX(), rectF.centerY(),  radius, new int[]{Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, Color.GREEN}, null, TileMode.CLAMP); The background paint style is stroke, and I cannot get all the colors to show. I thought I was not calculating the radius right but after trial and error, nothing works. Can you show me how to get all the colors to appear in a stroke?

Comment: Where you are passing in "null" for your radial gradient you need to pass in an int[] of stops for all the colors. The int[] should have one value - from 0-100 for each color in your gradient, otherwise the colors are evenly distributed from the center of the circle - although you are only seeing the outer part of it because it in contained in a stroke so you will have to play around with the numbers a bit to get all colors in the stroke.